# Laravel. Make redirects between subdomains

Tags: redirect, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm developing an app with an admin subdomain, so I have `admin.example.com` and `www.example.com`. My problem is: whenever an user tries to enter `admin.example.com` he should be redirected to a login page (if not logged in), which is in `www.example.com/login`

How can I make a redirect from `admin.example.com` to `www.example.com/login` ?? I've tried this in my `app/routes.php`:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.example.com'], function(){
  Route::get('/', 'AdminHomeController@getWelcome');
  Route::any("{all}", function(){App::abort(404);})->where('all', '.*');
  // I used this line to block access routes in admin.example.com not defined here
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'www.example.com'], function()
{
..... 
Route::controller('/', 'AuthController'); // here is defined getLogin
}
```

With this code I can do a `Redirect::to(action('AuthController@getLogin'))`. Although I'm not sure this is the correct way for achieving this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an `auth` filter to your `admin.example.com` group. In the filter, you would check if the user is authenticated; if they are not, then `return Redirect::guest(`www.example.com/login)`.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.example.com', 'before' => 'auth'], function(){
....
```

In your `auth` filter:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest( Config::get('app.url').'/login' );
});
```

After login, you can use `Redirect::intended()` to get back to where the user was trying to go in the first place.

Comment: I tried this, but it redirects me to `admin.example.com/login`

Comment: You can specify the full URL in the `Redirect::guest('http://www.example.com/login')`.

Comment: And, to prevent hardcoding the base URL, you could use `return Redirect::guest( Config::get('app.url').'/login' );`. This will read the URL from your `config/app` file, which you can change based on your environment—local vs. production, etc. (I edited the answer to include this.)

Comment: Almost there, but calling `return Redirect::guest(Config::get('app.url').'/login');` sends me to `admin.example.com/www.example.com/login`

Comment: Make sure your `'url'` value in `config/app` is prefixed with `http://`; it should read `'url' => 'http://www.example.com',`

Comment: Thanks. Now I have the intended behavior. After logging in I'm redirected to `admin.example.com` and I don't have to hardcode anything.

Comment: It's too bad that a named route isn't tied to the main domain if it is specified outside a route group.